# Can't send emails with PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, imap

I'm using LinuxMint 13 and I can't send emails from PHP scripts. I've ran into a lot of configuration with Postfix without any success so I decided to remove it.

I just want to be able to send emails to another computer or/and  any email address and to be able to execute functions like `imap_open()` or `imap_mail()`. When I had Postfix, these functions would return true, but nothing was sent. So now I'd like to be able to execute this functions. I also want to be able to send emails through an account I'm logged to.

Please tell me what's not working and which package(s) would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: So... in order you send emails... you decided to remove the email server from the equation?  I don't think that plan is going to work.

Comment: Maybe you could provide traces from you MTA which might help us understand what the problem is, and for us to perhaps move this question to another of our sites that would be more suitable for solving MTA configuration issues. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this so I don't understand what info I should provide. I've reinstalled Postfix.

Comment: Here's what I have in the mail log. Jul 11 00:23:55 default postfix/smtp[10503]: 28322202579: to=<xxx@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=613, delays=593/0.01/20/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=smtp.localdomain type=MX: Host not found, try again)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the PHP `mail()` function, you just need to install `sendmail` (`sudo apt-get install sendmail`).  It should set up everything you need to send mail.

Some major ISP's may block your mail because you don't meet requirements for sending (such as having a non-generic hostname, and you need a proper reverse DNS record for your IP address) but that should be all you need in order to send mail from PHP.

Comment: I've already installed sendmail. Please tell me more about what's blocking me.

Comment: Check to see if `mail()` is returning true or false first.  Then check server mail logs to see if the messages are being delivered or held due to errors.  `/var/log` is a good place to start looking.

Comment: mail isn't returning anything. The code freezes when I call it.

Comment: You may want to mention that in the question.  Could be your system is hanging trying to connect to a remote host to send mail.  Wireshark may help at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's default `mail` function.  [Here's the documentation on that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).  It could work something like the following (example from the documentation):

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

If you're having troubles with that you could use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), which is a library which gives you more control over the mail you're sending.  They even provide [some pretty killer examples](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examples).

Comment: Do I have to install or configure something else?

Comment: Not usually. However, sometimes you may have to configure the way PHP is set up on your server.  http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm may help.

Comment: PHP is properly configured according to online tutorials, but I think the problem comes from the domain name, and the settings of this kind. I haven't edited them. How do I do that?

Comment: That depends on your web or domain host.  For that you should search their FAQ or support for answers.

Comment: I'm working on my laptop. I want to upload the scripts to a server later.

Comment: So you're using a localhost?  That's a completely different setup.  This link may be able to help you: http://www.jacmoe.dk/how-to-send-test-emails-using-php-mail-from-your-local-wamp-installation

Comment: I've been desperately searching for answers and I just found somewhere that I can't send emails if I don't have a domain name.They say that mailboxes won't accept it.

Comment: They will accept it, but sometimes it may be routed to the spam folder.  Again, email has a lot of variables.  In this case, it'd be up to the receiving email's provider to judge this as spam or not.